# StringBuilder cuts off after ~1500 Characters

Tags: java, stringbuilder

im building a String with Stringbuilder, in the end i want to email this String, but it seems like the text always is cut off after ~1500 characters.

```
List<Itprojekte> items = tableModel.getAllElements();
    StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder(items.size() * 80);
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");

        for (Itprojekte project : items) {
            body.append("Time:\n").append(df.format(project.getTime())).append("\n\n");
            body.append(lineSeparator);
            body.append("Name:\n").append(project.getName()).append("\n\n");
            body.append(lineSeparator);
            body.append("Place:\n").append(project.getTown()).append("\n\n");
            body.append(lineSeparator);
            body.append("Description:\n").append(project.getDescription()).append("\n\n");
            body.append(lineSeparator);
            body.append("Link:\n").append(project.getUrl().trim());
            body.append(lineSeparator);
            body.append(lineSeparator);
        }



        try {
        mailto("Test", body.toString());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProjectsResultjForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProjectsResultjForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The mailto:

```
public static void mailto(String subject,
        String body) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    String uriStr = String.format("mailto:?subject=%s&body=%s",
            urlEncode(subject),
            urlEncode(body));
    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(uriStr));
}
```

Comment: I supose you are using C#? Please add a tag for your programming language.

Comment: Looks like Java to me.

Comment: Ideally this shouldn't be the case, but if you need set the capacity explicitly using Capacity property

Comment: method names starting with small case, must be java

Comment: @DenisHartwood, how do you know there is a ~1500 character cut-off? Have you printed the string to console or did you in fact email the string?

Comment: When i press the "Send as Email"-Button the program builds the String, opens my email-client and writes the string in the email... i copied it in word and counted the characters....

Comment: Add a log line with subject.toString().length() to make sure the subject is longer.

Comment: Im not a nativ englisch speaker, so its quite hard for me to understand everything. What is a "log line"? Where schould i put "subject.toString().length()" in my code?

Comment: Converted the Stringbuilder to String before giving it to my email-client, still cut off, so it seems to be the conversion to string causing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**All okay upto here.**
First you might lower resources, speed things up with an initial capacity to StringBuilder.

```
    StringBuilder subject = new StringBuilder(items.size() * 80);

    for (Itprojekte project : items) {
        ...
    }
    if (subject.length() < 1500) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProjectsResultjForm.class.getName()).log(Level.WARN,
                "*** Mail body: {0}", subject);
    }
```

The **error** is in the mailto URL: URLs are limited in size, 1600 or so.

Comment: Same thing, string gets cut off...
I get the String in my email client, thats just fine, but only the first ~1500 characters, the rest gets cut off... "subject" here is the body!

Comment: Converted to String and looked into it.. the String is ok and has all the information, seems like the Problem might be on the ways to the email-client -.-

Comment: I just now saw the mailto URL being built. That is limited. `Desktop.mail(URI)` will probably fail too (and even ofter).

Comment: Yep, made my way through the Program with breakpoints.... is there a way to change that or to unlimit the size of an url? There must be a possibility to write more than 1600 characters into an email from a program....

Comment: One might try javax.mail, but then need credentials. I generally used a company server. The best way I can think of is display the text, copy the text to clipboard, and leave it to the user.

Comment: for using javax.mail the user has to typ in their email adress etc. right? Multipel users are using this program, i just want to open an email client with the text-.-

Comment: Yes javax.mail can best be used if there is a server, and the server may send the text, like in greeting e-cards.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that you have to pay attention is the heap space available.